# export csv with current date and time as filename

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to use php to put SQL results into a .csv file where the file name will be the current date and time.

The search query below works if I insert a unique filename manually, but when I try to concatenate the `$date` variable as below, I get a mysql syntax error in terminal.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
$query_text = "SELECT Code FROM Country WHERE HeadOfState = 'Big Bird' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/' . $date . '.csv'";

$result = mysql_query($query_text);
```

This seems logical to me from the context of PHP, but SQL doesn't seem to like it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

break out of your code with double quotes.

```
 $query_text = "SELECT Code FROM Country WHERE HeadOfState = 'Big Bird' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/" . $date . ".csv'";
```